# Why does growing more muscle push out veins to surface?

Tags: muscle, hypertrophy

I have learned that gaining muscle make veins more visible **not because they increase vein size** but because they **push out veins** more. But, why? Why does gaining muscles push out the veins more?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't, rather it's having low body fat, and hence minimal subcutaneous fat to hide the veins, which makes veins more visible. That's why strongmen, who typically have enormous amounts of muscle, but also higher levels of body fat, don't have particularly visible veins.

Comment: Mostly true, however the body will also adapt to stress on the muscle by also growing new blood vessels (Neovasculogenesis) to meet the increase demands for oxygen in a working muscle. These aren't usually the visible veins, however.